# Javascript - while loop runs infinite intermittently?

Tags: javascript, while-loop, infinite-loop

If I run the following function in console (with an integer between 1 and 10 for length), it crashes the browser.

```
function getStr(length) {
  var random = Math.round(Math.random() * Math.pow(10, length)).toString();
   while(random.length < length) {
       random = random.padEnd('1');
   }
   return random;
}
```

I can't figure out why.

Comment: You are never changing the value of random.length. If random.length < length you are just console.logging infinitely.

Comment: I think you want to use `while(random < length){}` then inside the while, change the `random` variable value

Comment: You've misunderstood [`padEnd`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padEnd)  method.

Comment: Get rid of the loop, and do `return random.padEnd(length, "1")`

Comment: Based on suggestions here,
I changed 
`random.padEnd('1')`
to 
`random = random.padEnd('1')

That does not work either

Comment: Thank you @Teemu.
I did indeed. Looked up the function
This solved the problem: 
Removed the while loop
And added:
`return random.padEnd(7, '1')

Answer (score 0):

You have no way of changing the value of random.length, breaking out of the loop, or changing the `while` condition. You need some way to get out of it or else it will loop forever.

```
function getStr(length) {
    var random = Math.round(Math.random() * Math.pow(10, 
    length)).toString();
    while(random.length < length) {
        console.log(random.length, ‘-’, length);
        length = random.length + 1; //Change the value of length
        // OR you can just break out of the loop
        break; // Break out of the loop
    }
    return random;
}
```

[Here is a resource to learn more about JavaScript while loops](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_while.asp).

Comment: Sorry,
I put the wrong code in there, i will edit it. I had put console log for debugging,
This is the original function: 

`function getStr(length) {
  var random = Math.round(Math.random() * Math.pow(10, length)).toString();
   while(random.length < length) {
       random.padEnd('1');
   }
   return random;
}`